# java ant: specify which java installation should be used to run

Tags: java, ant, 32bit-64bit

is it possible to specify which installation of java on the system should be used to run a 
java task? 
if yes, how?

in my case i want to specify if i want to run the 32bit or the 64bit version.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what `jvm` attribute of the [`<java>` Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) is about.

**jvm**     - the command used to invoke the Java Virtual Machine, default is 'java'. The command is resolved by java.lang.Runtime.exec(). Ignored if fork is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

From http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

**fork** Whether to execute javac using the JDK compiler externally; defaults to no

**executable** Complete path to the javac executable to use in case of fork="yes". Defaults to the compiler of the Java version that is currently running Ant. Ignored if fork="no".
Since Ant 1.6 this attribute can also be used to specify the path to the executable when using jikes, jvc, gcj or sj.

Comment: thanks, but i am not talking about compilation, but about execution. so the task is not javac but java.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JAVACMD` environment variable (see [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#envvars))

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<java>` command doesn't let you specify the JVM, I'd suggest you use [`<exec>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) directly to execute the exact `java` binary and command line you want.